# please give me solution for that app reject for following reason i can't find solutions

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

> 4. 2 Design: Minimum Functionality
>      Guideline 4.2.2 - Design - Minimum Functionality

We noticed that your app only includes links, images, or content aggregated from the Internet with limited or no native iOS functionality. We understand that this content may be curated from the web specifically for your users, but since it does not sufficiently differ from a mobile web browsing experience, it is not appropriate for the App Store.

The next submission of this app may require a longer review time, and this app will not be eligible for an expedited review until this issue is resolved.

Next Steps

- Review the Minimum Functionality section of the App Store Review Guidelines.
- Ensure your app is compliant with all sections of the App Store Review Guidelines and the Terms & Conditions of the Apple Developer Program.
- Once your app is fully compliant, resubmit your app for review.

If you believe your app is compliant with the App Store Review Guidelines, you may submit an appeal. Alternatively, you may provide additional details about your app by replying directly to this message.

Comment: This is what apple said to you, we don't know you did and what your app is, from the above reason stated by apple it seems you are calling website inside UIWebView.

Comment: yes i using webview inside app just for showing amazon product review

Comment: and what functionalities you have in your app ? or that's all ?

Comment: users find products and relevant products from various online providers.
like amazon, ebay, walmart, etc  its showing all details and user can purchase any selected products thats navigate to site

Comment: I think you are simply calling websites in UIWebView then.

Comment: No. webview used for only products review

Comment: users find products and relevant products from various online providers. like amazon, ebay, walmart, etc : How you are getting them ? Are you displaying then in native controls ?

Comment: yes i am displaying then in native controls

Comment: Then explain them what your app does in reply at resolution center.

Comment: There's really [nothing that anybody here can do](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/65839); we aren't [Apple support](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/65839).This isn't a programming issue; this is about your business relationship to try to get Apple to distribute your product.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Apple App Store Review Process / app design / business requirements instead of directly about programming and coding.

Answer (score 0):

Please use some more native iOS functionality into your application. I think you have not used more functionality of ios and directly shown particular content of any website into your application which apple doesn't allow.

Answer (score 0):

> Your app should include features, content, and UI that elevate it
>   beyond a repackaged website. If your app is not particularly useful,
>   unique, or “app-like,” it doesn’t belong on the App Store

[App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#minimum-functionality)

Include features in your app that are specific to iOS platform (in case of an iOS app). Features that you wouldn't find on a website.

Features such as:

- swiping right/left on rows in a table to display certain usual
  actions to the user.
- pinching an image to zoom in/out.

Answer (score 0):

This rejection subjects tell that, your applcation some functions can not work as expectly.

What do I mean ?

I had Two IOS APPs they have two common mistakes that is rejected with this subject..

-Inside app buying, paying system was not work...
-So Apple that dont explain what is cause the rejection but just telling "Guideline 4.2 - Design - Minimum Functionality
"

After I solve paying system, apple approved that two app